# Attempting to use LetsEncrypt to run SSL-wrapped BaseHTTPServer in Python fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, lets-encrypt

I had a working HTTP server using `BaseHTTPServer` in Python, so I attempted to add an SSL cert to allow for https using LetsEncrypt, and now it won't serve any files or respond. No exceptions or errors thrown, nor will it serve any content.

```
server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 80)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
# I can comment out the following line and it'll work
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile=ssl_key, certfile=ssl_cert, server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()

#ssl_key = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'
#ssl_cert = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem'
```

Where `MyHandler` is the following:

```
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(204)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        return

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(204)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        return
```

Attempting to access the site via web browser from `https://example.com` returns a standard no-response "Server not found".

I followed the following instructions to generate a certificate using LetsEncrypt: https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-other

> `sudo apt-get install letsencrypt`

Followed by:

> `letsencrypt certonly --standalone -d example.com`

Is there any way I can easily figure out what the problem is here? Using Python 3.5. Happy to provide additional info if needed.

Comment: What does MyHandler do? Does it fork? What URL you are using to access it? Given the code the URL must include protocol https and also explicitly port 80 because this is not the standard port for https. Also, any non-https access will cause the server to stall for all users, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531146/truly-non-blocking-https-server-in-python.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich added the code for MyHandler, as well as info on the URL used to access it (https protocol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 80)
> ```
>
> Attempting to access the site via web browser from `https://example.com` returns a standard no-response "Server not found".

`https://host` without explicit port specification means that the server is accessed on the default port for the https protocol, which is 443. But, you have setup your server to use port 80 in `server_address`.

There are two ways to fix this: either explicitly specify a non-standard port for https in the URL, i.e. `https://host:80` or change the port in `server_address` from 80 to 443. The last option is probably the better one.

Comment: Mhmm, I managed to figure this out shortly after. However, now requests to `http://` do not work, presumably because I'm not binding to port 80. How can I support both protocols?

Comment: @EchoLogic: this is a different question then. But in short: you have to listen on both addresses. See [How do I write a python HTTP server to listen on multiple ports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680/how-do-i-write-a-python-http-server-to-listen-on-multiple-ports).